# Why Spring crashes with "No bean named .. is defined" when configuring RabbitMQ queues using a system property and SpEL?

Tags: spring-amqp

I have the following code in my context XML (among other things):

```
<rabbit:queue name="#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}" />

<rabbit:fanout-exchange name="si.test.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>
```

I first compile it using `mvn compile`. Then, when I want to run it with `mvn -Dconsumer1Queue=queue1 exec:java` it throws:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.BindingFactoryBean#0': **Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean '#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}' while
>   setting bean property 'destinationQueue'**; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: **No
>   bean named 'queue1' is defined**  at
>   [...]

The exception stops occurring when I either:

- change the `<rabbit:queue ...>` element to `<rabbit:queue name="queue1" />`, or
- comment out the `<rabbit:fanout-exchange ...>` element.

This is Spring Integration version 4.1.1

Why is this happening? Could this be related to [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-398)?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, seems like it is not doing a full string replace or doing it in the wrong order. We are using puppet for dynamic setup and hard-coding isn't really an option. Also we are using ant instead of maven but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't correct. See `binding`'s `queue` attribute docs:

> The bean name of the Queue to bind to this exchange.

So, you should add `id` to the `<rabbit:queue>` and use it as a value of the `binding`'s `queue` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this suggestion doesn't work as I'd hope. I tried: (1) <rabbit:queue id="#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}" /> - DOESN'T WORK, (2) <rabbit:queue name="#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}" id="#{systemProperties.consumer1Queue}" /> - DOESN'T WORK, (3) <rabbit:queue id="queue1" /> or <rabbit:queue name="queue1" />  - WORKS, but that's not setting it up dynamically. I think my original syntax should work because it works fine when used with environment variable "consumer2Queue" and <rabbit:queue name="${consumer2Queue}" />. Any other ideas?